# How to do both Add and Update in Entity Framework ASP.NET Core?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I want to do both updates and add in the same action method in ASP.NET Core by Entity Framework Core, but after making an addition to a list of records in the database, I cannot update the same records to the table. It always creates a new set of records.

What is my mistake? Can anybody please help me?

```
    
  [HttpPost]        
        public IActionResult InsertProductDetails()
        {
            using WebClient wc = new WebClient();
            string contentString = wc.DownloadString(baseurl);
            List<Dictionary<string, string>> ListJsonProductContent = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();          
            var token = JToken.Parse(contentString);
            if (token.Type == JTokenType.Array)  // "["
            {
                ListJsonProductContent = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Dictionary<string, string>>>(contentString);
            }
            else if (token.Type == JTokenType.Object) // "{"
            {
                var ObjectResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(contentString);
                foreach (var x in ObjectResponse)
                {
                    string key = x.Key.ToString();
                    string val = x.Value.ToString();
                    foreach (var dicItemML in JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Dictionary<string, string>>>(val))
                    {
                        ListJsonProductContent.Add(dicItemML);
                    }
                }
            }

            List<K360MappingMaster> ListMappedDataDb = new List<K360MappingMaster>();             
            var VLinqQuery = from KMM in _context.K360MappingMasters
                             where KMM.ApiUrl != null && KMM.ApiUrl == baseurl                            
                             select KMM;
            ListMappedDataDb = VLinqQuery.ToList();

            foreach (var dicItemML in ListJsonProductContent)
            {
                Dictionary<string, string> updItem = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                foreach (var itemMl in dicItemML)
                {
                    if (ListMappedDataDb.Select(s => s.ApiCatalog).ToList().Contains(itemMl.Key))
                    {
                        if (updItem.ContainsKey(ListMappedDataDb.Where(s => s.ApiCatalog == itemMl.Key).Select(s => s.K360Catalog).FirstOrDefault()))
                        {
                            if (ListMappedDataDb.Where(s => s.ApiCatalog == itemMl.Key).Select(s => s.K360Catalog).FirstOrDefault() == "Specification")
                            {
                                updItem[ListMappedDataDb.Where(s => s.ApiCatalog == itemMl.Key).Select(s => s.K360Catalog).FirstOrDefault()] += "<p>" + itemMl.Key + " :" + itemMl.Value + "<p>";
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                updItem[ListMappedDataDb.Where(s => s.ApiCatalog == itemMl.Key).Select(s => s.K360Catalog).FirstOrDefault()] += " " + itemMl.Value;
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (ListMappedDataDb.Where(s => s.ApiCatalog == itemMl.Key).Select(s => s.K360Catalog).FirstOrDefault() == "Specification")
                            {
                                updItem.Add(ListMappedDataDb.Where(s => s.ApiCatalog == itemMl.Key).Select(s => s.K360Catalog).FirstOrDefault(), "<p>" + itemMl.Key + " :" + itemMl.Value + "<p>");
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                updItem.Add(ListMappedDataDb.Where(s => s.ApiCatalog == itemMl.Key).Select(s => s.K360Catalog).FirstOrDefault(), itemMl.Value);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    dicItemML.Remove(itemMl.Key);
                }
                foreach (var itemM2 in updItem)
                {
                    dicItemML.Add(itemM2.Key, itemM2.Value);
                }
            }
          
             List<CatalogProduct> ListKp = new List<CatalogProduct>();

            foreach (var dicItem in ListJsonProductContent)
                    {
                        try
                        {                            
                            CatalogProduct Ctgkp = new CatalogProduct
                            {    
                                Name = dicItem.ContainsKey("Name") ? dicItem["Name"] : "No Product",
                                Slug = dicItem.ContainsKey("Name") ? string.Concat(dicItem["Name"].Where(c => !char.IsWhiteSpace(c))).ToLower() : "No Slug",
                                Price = dicItem.ContainsKey("Price") ? decimal.Parse(dicItem["Price"], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) : default,
                                ShortDescription = dicItem.ContainsKey("ShortDescription") ? dicItem["ShortDescription"] : null,
                                Description = dicItem.ContainsKey("Description") ? dicItem["Description"] : null,
                                Specification = dicItem.ContainsKey("Specification") ? dicItem["Specification"] : null,
                                RatingAverage = dicItem.ContainsKey("RatingAverage") ? double.Parse(dicItem["RatingAverage"], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) : null,

                                MetaTitle = dicItem.ContainsKey("MetaTitle") ? dicItem["MetaTitle"] : null,
                                MetaKeywords = dicItem.ContainsKey("MetaKeywords") ? dicItem["MetaKeywords"] : null,
                                MetaDescription = dicItem.ContainsKey("MetaDescription") ? dicItem["MetaDescription"] : null,
                                Sku = dicItem.ContainsKey("Sku") ? dicItem["Sku"] : null,
                                Gtin = dicItem.ContainsKey("Gtin") ? dicItem["Gtin"] : null,
                                NormalizedName = dicItem.ContainsKey("NormalizedName") ? dicItem["NormalizedName"] : null,

                                StockQuantity = dicItem.ContainsKey("StockQuantity") ? int.Parse(dicItem["StockQuantity"], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) : 50,
                                ReviewsCount = dicItem.ContainsKey("ReviewsCount") ? int.Parse(dicItem["ReviewsCount"], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) : default,
                                DisplayOrder = dicItem.ContainsKey("DisplayOrder") ? int.Parse(dicItem["DisplayOrder"], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) : 1,
                                OldPrice = dicItem.ContainsKey("OldPrice") ? decimal.Parse(dicItem["OldPrice"], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) : null,
                                SpecialPrice = dicItem.ContainsKey("SpecialPrice") ? decimal.Parse(dicItem["SpecialPrice"], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) : null,
                                SpecialPriceStart = dicItem.ContainsKey("SpecialPriceStart") ? DateTimeOffset.Parse(dicItem["SpecialPriceStart"], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) : null,
                                SpecialPriceEnd = dicItem.ContainsKey("SpecialPriceEnd") ? DateTimeOffset.Parse(dicItem["SpecialPriceEnd"], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) : null,

                                IsPublished = true,
                                PublishedOn = DateTimeOffset.Now,
                                CreatedById = 10,
                                IsDeleted = false,
                                CreatedOn = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow,
                                LatestUpdatedOn = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow,
                                LatestUpdatedById = 10,
                                HasOptions = false,
                                IsVisibleIndividually = true,
                                IsFeatured = true,
                                IsCallForPricing = false,
                                IsAllowToOrder = true,
                                StockTrackingIsEnabled = true
                        };
                            ListKp.Add(Ctgkp);
                           
                }

                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            TempData["Exceptionmsg"] = ex;
                            return RedirectToAction("Index");
                            throw;
                        }
                    }

            int numP = 0;
            try
            {
                using (var transaction = _context.Database.BeginTransaction())
                {
                    int getcount = (from gcM in _context.CatalogProducts
                                    select gcM).Count();

                    if (getcount == 0)
                    {
                        _context.CatalogProducts.AddRange(ListKp);
                        _context.SaveChanges();

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        var catalogProducts = (from gcM in _context.CatalogProducts select gcM).ToList();
                        for (int i = 0; i < catalogProducts.Count; i++)
                        {
                            catalogProducts[i].Name = ListKp[i].Name;
                            catalogProducts[i].Price = ListKp[i].Price;
                            catalogProducts[i].Description = ListKp[i].Description;
                            catalogProducts[i].Specification = ListKp[i].Specification;
                            //...
                        }

                        _context.CatalogProducts.UpdateRange(catalogProducts);
                        _context.SaveChanges();

                    }


                    transaction.Commit();
                }
                if (numP > 0)
                {
                    TempData["Sucessmsg"] = "No conflicts. " + numP + " product details saved.";

                    (from p in _context.K360MappingMasters
                     where p.ApiUrl == baseurl
                     select p).ToList()
                                .ForEach(x => x.InsertStatusFlag = true);
                    _context.SaveChanges();

                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                TempData["Exceptionmsg"] = ex;
                return RedirectToAction("Index"); ;
                throw;
            }
           

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

I have accepted your answer. Thanks. But I have few more clarifications need for the same question

1.CatalogProduct table has Auto increment primary key Id field only. I am inserting data from JSON URL. The unique field should be the product name. How to check whether the product name already exists in the table before adding/updating records.

2.If I need to add another JSON URL data, how do I differentiate the two URL product details?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no entities in db being tracked when doing Update, so it will directly add them.

You can try the below codes.

```
else
{
    var catalogProducts= (from gcM in _context.CatalogProducts select gcM).ToList();
    for (int i = 0; i < catalogProducts.Count; i++)
    {
        catalogProducts[i].Name = ListKp[i].Name;
        catalogProducts[i].Price = ListKp[i].Price;
        //...
    }
                
    _context.CatalogProducts.UpdateRange(catalogProducts);
    numP = _context.SaveChanges();
                
}
```

**Update:**

```
using (var transaction = _context.Database.BeginTransaction())
{
    var catalogProducts = _context.CatalogProducts.ToList();
    foreach(var kp in ListKp)
    {
        if(!catalogProducts.Any(x => x.Name == kp.Name)){
            _context.CatalogProducts.Add(kp);
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }
        else
        {
            //Use AutoMapper automatically do the mapping
            var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<CatalogProduct, CatalogProduct>().ForMember(c => c.Id, opt => opt.Ignore()));
            var oldone = catalogProducts.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Name == kp.Name);
            var mapper = config.CreateMapper();
            oldone = mapper.Map<CatalogProduct,CatalogProduct>(kp, oldone);
            _context.CatalogProducts.Update(oldone);
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
    transaction.Commit();
}
```

Comment: thanks for your timing response.can i need to add again column names like catalogProducts[i].Name = ListKp[i].Name;
        catalogProducts[i].Price = ListKp[i].Price; in the update method again? almost 20 columns are there. its already added in add block. is any other way to fetch column names dynamically?

Comment: I have accepted your answer. Thanks. But I have few more clarifications need for the same question

1.CatalogProduct table has Auto increment primary key Id field only. I am inserting data from JSON URL. The unique field should be the product name. How to check whether the product name already exists in the table before adding/updating records.

2.If I need to add another JSON URL data, how do I differentiate the two URL product details?

Comment: So, you want to add the record if the name doesn't exist and update when it already exists?

Comment: yes, you are correct. but also need to know what happens if I add data from another dynamic JSON URL

Comment: if add a new product by the backend and try to update from the page, it shows an error. need to check product name exists before add/update.please help me

Comment: I have update my answer, but I don't understand your sencond question.

Comment: Thanks.Code working fine. Don't know about auto wrapper so far. Very much appreciated your coding standards. If needed feel free to share any changes in my code for the remaining part of that action method

Comment: A small doubt regarding JSON. [link] (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wedeploy-examples/supermarket-web-example/master/products.json). In this URL [type] array key is the main root object I guess. under these 7 types, the product names listed, and all other properties are displayed. How to identity from JSON file, the main root directory object dynamically?

Comment: ,For this Json [link] (https://gist.githubusercontent.com/dpetersen/1237910/raw/6ceb2161f756d4b4d5c22754d1ed8d869249f186/product_grid.js), the same product-name exists in 2 root directory. when adding it inserted all 8 records but during update, it updates the first 4 records. Probably code checking unique product name and it's fine for all. But for these rare cases what we need to do

Comment: sorry to disturb you. I need some more tasks with your add/update code. I have created a new thread for this. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66589181/add-and-update-in-entity-framework-asp-net-core), please have a look into it and help me if possible

Comment: Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66589181/add-and-update-in-asp-net-core-with-entity-framework