# Add and Update in ASP.NET Core with Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am doing add and update JSON data into the SQL table.

Below Code working for adding and updating a new set of records

```cs
List<CatalogProduct> ListKp = new List<CatalogProduct>();
using (var transaction = _context.Database.BeginTransaction())
{
    try
    {   
        int numP = 0;
        var catalogProducts = _context.CatalogProducts.ToList();
        foreach (var kp in ListKp)
        {
            if (!catalogProducts.Any(x => x.Name == kp.Name))
            {
                _context.CatalogProducts.Add(kp);
            }
            else
            {
                //Use AutoMapper automatically do the mapping
                var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<CatalogProduct, CatalogProduct>().ForMember(c => c.Id, opt => opt.Ignore()));
                var oldone = catalogProducts.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Name == kp.Name);
                var mapper = config.CreateMapper();
                oldone = mapper.Map<CatalogProduct, CatalogProduct>(kp, oldone);
                _context.CatalogProducts.Update(oldone);
            }
        }
        numP = _context.SaveChanges();                        
        transaction.Commit();
        return Json("No conflicts. " + numP + " product details saved.");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        transaction.Rollback();
        return Json("Error occurred." + ex.Message);
        throw new Exception();
    }
}
```

Sample JSON data

```json
{
    "title": "Brown eggs",
    "type": "dairy",
    "description": "Raw organic brown eggs in a basket",
    "filename": "0.jpg",
    "height": 600,
    "width": 400,
    "price": 28.1,
    "rating": 4
},
{
    "title": "Sweet fresh stawberry",
    "type": "fruit",
    "description": "Sweet fresh stawberry on the wooden table",
    "filename": "1.jpg",
    "height": 450,
    "width": 299,
    "price": 29.45,
    "rating": 4
},
```

First I will add [type] key object values from the above JSON into the products table [NAME] field. It will add a new set of records.

When I try to update the products table [NAME] field with [title] key object values, again it will add a new set of records.

Need to update products table [NAME] field without adding again.

I don't know how to check already existing records in a table with model list values. Already spent much time on this. I am new to EF Core, please anybody can help me

Complete Code

```
 [HttpPost]
public IActionResult InsertProductDetails()
{
                using WebClient wc = new WebClient();
                string contentString = wc.DownloadString(baseurl);

                List<Dictionary<string, string>> ListJsonProductContent = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();
                var token = JToken.Parse(contentString);
                if (token.Type == JTokenType.Array)  // "["
                {
                    ListJsonProductContent = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Dictionary<string, string>>>(contentString);
                }
                else if (token.Type == JTokenType.Object) // "{"
                {
                    var ObjectResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(contentString);
                    foreach (var x in ObjectResponse)
                    {
                        string key = x.Key.ToString();
                        string val = x.Value.ToString();
                        foreach (var dicItemML in JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Dictionary<string, string>>>(val))
                        {
                            ListJsonProductContent.Add(dicItemML);
                        }
                    }
                }                

                List <K360MappingMaster> ListMappedDataDb = new List<K360MappingMaster>();
                var VLinqQuery = from KMM in _context.K360MappingMasters
                                 where KMM.ThirdPartyBaseUrlName != null && KMM.ThirdPartyBaseUrlName == baseurl
                                 select KMM;
                ListMappedDataDb = VLinqQuery.ToList();

                foreach (var dicItemML in ListJsonProductContent)
                {                   
                    Dictionary<string, string> updItem = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                    foreach (var itemMl in dicItemML)
                    {                        
                       
                        if (ListMappedDataDb.Select(s => s.ApiCatalog).ToList().Contains(itemMl.Key))
                        {
                            if (updItem.ContainsKey(ListMappedDataDb.Where(s => s.ApiCatalog == itemMl.Key).Select(s => s.K360Catalog).FirstOrDefault()))
                            {
                                if (ListMappedDataDb.Where(s => s.ApiCatalog == itemMl.Key).Select(s => s.K360Catalog).FirstOrDefault() == "Specification")
                                {
                                    updItem[ListMappedDataDb.Where(s => s.ApiCatalog == itemMl.Key).Select(s => s.K360Catalog).FirstOrDefault()] += "<p>" + itemMl.Key + " :" + itemMl.Value + "<p>";
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    updItem[ListMappedDataDb.Where(s => s.ApiCatalog == itemMl.Key).Select(s => s.K360Catalog).FirstOrDefault()] += " " + itemMl.Value;
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                if (ListMappedDataDb.Where(s => s.ApiCatalog == itemMl.Key).Select(s => s.K360Catalog).FirstOrDefault() == "Specification")
                                {
                                    updItem.Add(ListMappedDataDb.Where(s => s.ApiCatalog == itemMl.Key).Select(s => s.K360Catalog).FirstOrDefault(), "<p>" + itemMl.Key + " :" + itemMl.Value + "<p>");
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    updItem.Add(ListMappedDataDb.Where(s => s.ApiCatalog == itemMl.Key).Select(s => s.K360Catalog).FirstOrDefault(), itemMl.Value);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        dicItemML.Remove(itemMl.Key);
                    }
                    foreach (var itemM2 in updItem)
                    {
                        dicItemML.Add(itemM2.Key, itemM2.Value);
                    }
                }

                List<CatalogProduct> ListKp = new List<CatalogProduct>();
                foreach (var dicItem in ListJsonProductContent)
                {                   
                    CatalogProduct Ctgkp = new CatalogProduct
                    {
                        Name = dicItem.ContainsKey("Name") ? dicItem["Name"] : "No Product",
                        Slug = dicItem.ContainsKey("Name") ? string.Concat(dicItem["Name"].Where(c => !char.IsWhiteSpace(c))).ToLower() : "No Slug",
                        Price = dicItem.ContainsKey("Price") ? decimal.Parse(dicItem["Price"], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) : default,
                        ShortDescription = dicItem.ContainsKey("ShortDescription") ? dicItem["ShortDescription"] : null,
                        Description = dicItem.ContainsKey("Description") ? dicItem["Description"] : null,
                        Specification = dicItem.ContainsKey("Specification") ? dicItem["Specification"] : null,
                        RatingAverage = dicItem.ContainsKey("RatingAverage") ? double.Parse(dicItem["RatingAverage"], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) : null};
                ListKp.Add(Ctgkp);
               }
using (var transaction = _context.Database.BeginTransaction())
                {
                    try
                    {
                        int numP = 0;
                        var catalogProducts = _context.CatalogProducts.ToList();
                        foreach (var kp in ListKp)
                        {
                            if (!catalogProducts.Any(x => x.Name == kp.Name))
                            {
                                _context.CatalogProducts.Add(kp);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                //Use AutoMapper automatically do the mapping
                                var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<CatalogProduct, CatalogProduct>().ForMember(c => c.Id, opt => opt.Ignore()));
                                var oldone = catalogProducts.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Name == kp.Name);
                                var mapper = config.CreateMapper();
                                oldone = mapper.Map<CatalogProduct, CatalogProduct>(kp, oldone);
                                _context.CatalogProducts.Update(oldone);
                            }
                        }
                        numP = _context.SaveChanges();
                        (from q in _context.K360MappingMasters
                         where q.ThirdPartyBaseUrlName == baseurl
                         select q).ToList().ForEach(x => x.InsertStatusFlag = true);
                        _context.SaveChanges();
                        transaction.Commit();
                        return Json("No conflicts. " + numP + " product details saved.");
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        transaction.Rollback();
                        return Json("Error occurred." + ex.Message);
                        throw new Exception();
                    }
                }
```

Comment: You have to show your dbcontext  CatalogProduct

Comment: @Sergey, Updated complete code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the core code:

```
var catalogProducts = _context.CatalogProducts.ToList();
foreach (var kp in ListKp)
{
    if (!catalogProducts.Any(x => x.Name == kp.Name))
        _context.CatalogProducts.Add(kp);
    else
    {
        //Use AutoMapper automatically do the mapping
        var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<CatalogProduct, CatalogProduct>().ForMember(c => c.Id, opt => opt.Ignore()));
        var oldone = catalogProducts.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Name == kp.Name);
        var mapper = config.CreateMapper();
        oldone = mapper.Map<CatalogProduct, CatalogProduct>(kp, oldone);
        _context.CatalogProducts.Update(oldone);
    }
}
```

The first detail will be whether your DbContext was set up to disable change tracking proxies. For instance if the following code is in your DbContext constructor or when the DbContext is created:

```
Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
```

Many teams turn off proxies when they encounter performance problems tripping over lazy loading. (instead of fixing the data access approach to avoid the lazy loading) Disabling proxies and change tracking makes update scenarios uglier. If these are off by default then I would recommend enabling them temporarily for this operation:

```
_context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = true;
_context.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = true;
```

`var catalogProducts = _context.CatalogProducts.ToList();` is going to fetch all catalog products from your DB. Depending on your data size this may not be practical. I'd suggest reading these one by one or consolidating the product names from the XML into a list and fetch the desired ones using `Contains`. Fetching each item by name /w change tracking enabled can be simplified to:

```
// Avoid re-initializing automapper EVERY loop iteration.
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<CatalogProduct, CatalogProduct>()
            .ForMember(c => c.Id, opt => opt.Ignore()));
var mapper = config.CreateMapper();

foreach (var kp in ListKp)
{
    var existingCatalogProduct = _context.CatalogProducts.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Name == kp.Name);
    if (existingCatalogProduct == null)
        _context.CatalogProducts.Add(kp);
    else
        mapper.Map<CatalogProduct, CatalogProduct>(kp, existingCatalogProduct);
}

// ...
_context.SaveChanges();
```

If the Product entity has any navigation properties I would recommend setting those to `Ignore` as well.

We don't need to call `Update` when using change tracking. EF will automatically compose `UPDATE` statements for changed values on records *if* those values actually change as a result of the map copying over new values.  With `Mapper.Map<src,dest>` I'm not sure what the return value references, if it passes back "dest" or a new object reference. You can ignore the return value, the method will update the values in the "dest" object reference. If the return value is a different object reference than "dest" then that could explain why it is treating the record as a new row as it would be a separate reference.

When you are expecting a single record, use the `Single` / `SingleOrDefault` rather than the `First` variant methods. `First` should only be used if you expect possible multiples and should always be used with an `OrderBy` clause.

Update:

If Name is not enough to uniquely identify a record to update vs. insert then you can change the filter to provide enough detail to try and identify the row before determining if an insert is required:

```
var existingCatalogProduct = _context.CatalogProducts
    .SingleOrDefault(x => x.Name == kp.Name 
        && x.ProductType = kp.ProductType
        && x.Category = kp.Category /*etc*/ );
```

This way if you find an existing catalog product row you can update the remaining details based with the Map call, or insert a new entry if no row is returned.

Comment: thanks for your clear explanation first. 1. _context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled,_context.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled settings not handled in my project. Where I need to set it to true.Its global settings or in this action method? 2.If the Product entity has any navigation properties I would recommend setting those to Ignore as well--> I am not clear on this. The product table is the heart of the project and many tables have to refer to it.

Comment: I am inserting records from dynamic JSON URLs so it won't have any primary key id fields or unique reference fields. Before doing the insert I am doing mapping for product catalogs. Need to map the matching objects from JSON key with column names from the table.

Comment: [Sample link](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wedeploy-examples/supermarket-web-example/master/products.json). I need to map from these 8 objects(title, type...rating) with some 20 columns from the table. After mapping needs to insert only those object's values from the JSON URL into the products table. The insert may happen as single or multiple times but needs to avoid duplication in the products table each time

Comment: If you don't have any code that disables the change tracking / proxies then you can use the above code to perform updates without having to explicitly call `.Update()`. `Update` is really only applicable when dealing with detached entities. Leveraging the change tracking results in an UPDATE SQL statement only if values change, and only for the values that actually change. `Update()` will generate an UPDATE SQL statement for all columns and even if no values actually changed.  I expanded the answer to hopefully help if you need more columns than Name to identify a row to update vs. insert.

Comment: I am getting the below error when I try to use change tracking/proxies. 'K360DbContext' does not contain a definition for 'Configuration' and no extension method 'Configuration' accepting a first argument of type 'type' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?).

Comment: really thanks for your explanation, and I have learned a lot. I have changed the auto wrapper code. code working fine. Don't know how to use change tracking/proxies in my code as I am getting an error.

Comment: but sill I am not getting an answer to my question. First I will add [type] key object values from the above JSON into the products table [NAME] field. It will add a new set of records.

When I try to update the products table [NAME] field with [title] key object values, again it will add a new set of records.

Need to update products table [NAME] field without adding again.

Comment: As per your updated answer, as of now, the Name column is unique. I do validation during mapping JSON key objects with table columns. So it's enough to check the Name column alone. But my issue is when I map [type] JSON key object with the Name column of the table, it inserts a new set of type object values. But next, when I change the mapping to [title] JSON key object with Name column of the table, it will not update with title object values in the Name column. It again creates a new set of records for title object values. in the table.

Comment: [Sample link](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wedeploy-examples/supermarket-web-example/master/products.json)

Comment: foreach (var dicItemML in ListJsonProductContent)
                { foreach (var itemMl in dicItemML){
                        var catalogProductsCheck = _context.CatalogProducts.ToList();
                        var result = catalogProductsCheck.Select(s => s.Name).ToList().Contains(itemMl.Value);
                        if (result == true)
                        {
                            _context.CatalogProducts.RemoveRange(_context.CatalogProducts.Where(c => c.Name == itemMl.Value));
                            _context.SaveChanges();
                        }}